# How to plot and visualize the forecasts of time series future values with auto-regression?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want  to plot the time series and forecasts of its future values. I am using autoregression model. I am not sure if the strategy I am using is correct or not. But I want to estimate time series data for 15 timestamps in the future. I expect to have  a fill between different possibilities:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import convolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

def moving_average(y, period):
    buffer = []
    for i in range(period, len(y)):
        buffer.append(y[i - period : i].mean())
    return buffer

def auto_regressive(y, p, d, q, future_count):
    """
    p = the order (number of time lags)
    d = degree of differencing
    q = the order of the moving-average
    """
    buffer = np.copy(y).tolist()
    for i in range(future_count):
        ma = moving_average(np.array(buffer[-p:]), q)
        forecast = buffer[-1]
        for n in range(0, len(ma), d):
            forecast -= buffer[-1 - n] - ma[n]
        buffer.append(forecast)
    return buffer



y=[60, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -2, 0, -2, 6, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, -1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2]
x=[1549984749, 1549984751, 1549984755, 1549984761, 1549984768, 1549984769, 1549984770, 1549984774, 1549984780, 1549984783, 1549984786, 1549984787, 1549984788,
   1549984794, 1549984797, 1549984855, 1549984923, 1549984930, 1549984955, 1549985006, 1549985008, 1549985027, 1549985086, 1549985091, 1549985101, 1549985115,
   1549985116, 1549985118, 1549985130, 1549985130, 1549985139, 1549985141, 1549985146, 1549985154, 1549985178, 1549985192, 1549985203, 1549985217, 1549985245,
   1549985288, 1549985311, 1549985316, 1549985425, 1549985447, 1549985460, 1549985463, 1549985489, 1549985561, 1549985595, 1549985610]
x=np.array(x)
print(np.size(x))
y=np.array(y)
print(np.size(y))

future_count = 15
predicted_15 = auto_regressive(y,20,1,2,future_count)

plt.plot(x[len(x) - len(predicted_15):], predicted_15)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
plt.show()
```

But I got this error:

```
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (15,) and (65,)
```

Comment: I suppose, x and y must be in the same length otherwise you hit that error message. I suggest you adjust them in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error as `predicted_15` contains `y` as well as your forecasted values (so `y` has length 65). You want to plot only the forecasted values (length 15).

```py
plt.plot(x[len(x) - len(predicted_15):], predicted_15[len(x):])
```

Having said this, you need to consider what x-values these predicted y values correspond to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have a question please. I want to plot  possible values in the future that means. The lenght of my x array is 50 I want to plot the possible 15 future values and their suitable forecast.  But by my code does not give me the expected results. Could please help me?

Comment: If you feel my response answered your original question please consider accepting it. As for your further question, you really should start another question. Having said that, I think I understand what you're doing wrong. You start with 50 (x, y) points, and predict the future 15 y points. But what x values do these correspond to? You should end up with 65 (x, y) points

Comment: I am just trying to interpret you answer. I am sure If I got the right result. Initially I have an array with  50 size for x and y, I count 15 timestamp to check their possible future values. But I got the forecast plot over the initial data. Do you understand me ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. However, I'd consider taking a look at the [```statsmodels```](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) package. In particular there is an option to fit autoregressive models with [```statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR```](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR). Built in to this is a ```predict``` method, which i'm sure you'll find helpful